# Is this a proper algorithm/time complexity for finding a value in this matrix?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

```
You have a n by n matrix that increases in value going from left to right 
and from top to bottom. Here is an example matrix: 

1 2 3 4 
2 3 4 5 
3 4 5 6 
4 5 6 7 

Now you have to find a "divide and conquer" algorithm to find if a value 'S'
is in this sorted matrix. Find a recurrence relation and state the time
complexity.
```

Here is my solution:

```
1. Find bottom left value (Time Steps: 1)
2. If 'S' is greater than this value, move right, otherwise, move up
3. Worse case, you traverse a whole row to the right or a whole column up.
   -So let this be notated as 'n' (the size of the row/column)
4. The time complexity is O(n + 1), so O(n)
```

Is this correct? Also, how would I represent this runtime as a recurrence?

EDIT: Just realized that my first step is probably not just 1 time step. It is most likely a bit under n^2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is flawed. What if

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 7 9
4 6 8 10
```

and it is required to find 5. Your path looks like (numbers mean order travelled)

```
 -  -  -  -
 -  - (5)(6)
 - (3)(4) -
(1)(2) -  -
```

I claim that complexity is $\mathscr{O}(n)$. 
In fact, the distance is [Taxicab distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), i.e. no returned back, just zig-zag path. 
To see this, imagine (not related from above),

```
 -  -  -  -
 - (6)(5) -
 -  - (4) -
(1)(2)(3) -
```

By your definition, if $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are seen, then $\forall i$, we have $x_i <x_{i+1} <x_{i+2}$ or $x_i <x_{i+2} <x_{i+1}$ or $x_{i+2} <x_{i+1} <x_i$ or $x_{i+1} <x_{i+2} <x_i$. 
So, $(6)>(2)$, a contradiction by construction. 
Similarly,

```
 -  -  -  -
(3)(4)(5) -
(2) - (6) -
(1) -  -  -
```

is impossible. It might be difficult to write purely symbolically, tell me if this extent of formalness is enough?